# MenuItem doesn't show the ripple effect on my device

Tags: android, navigationview

I am doing an app with **NavigationView** and I have a problem when I touch on MenuItem. In the Android Emulator it shows the ripple effect but when I test it on my Device (Samsung Galaxy Note 8) it does not appear:

[image: Android Emulator]

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note 8]

NavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_selected_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_selected_item"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

nav_selected_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe due to incorrect configuration of NavigationView; I am not sure what is preventing ripple effect on the phone. Can You try this and reply me back. 
At first, Add itemBackground into NavigationView inside your xml file the following attribute:

`app:itemBackground="@drawable/ripple_navigation_selector"`

Also, then inside the drawable-v21 folder, add ripple_navigation_selector.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/submit_btn_ripple_color" >
<item android:drawable="@color/accentColor" /> <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@android:color/white" /> </ripple>`
Since ripple effect is on devices with API 21 or above. It may work, tell me if it really helps you.

Comment: It does not works. I have to say that both devices are +21 API. And maybe you need to see that If I drag it shows the effect (on Samsung Galaxy Note 8): https://i.gyazo.com/ee568acfd09167a91ed02aa519712c19.gif